# Converting a list of Integers and Strings to purely a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list whose contents are:

```
x = ['A', 2, 'B', 2, 'C', 2, 'D', 2, 'a', 4, 'b', 2, 'c', 1, 'd', 2]
```

I want the output as:

```
A2B2C2D2a4b2c1d2
```

I tried with the line:

```
print(''.join(str(x)))
```

But it gives me an error that says:

```
print(''.join(str(x)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
```

Guess it's occurring because of those integers along with the strings.

How to tackle this to get the desired output as mentioned above?

Comment: `print(''.join(map(str, x)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
''.join(map(str, x))
```

**Code**:

```
x = ['A', 2, 'B', 2, 'C', 2, 'D', 2, 'a', 4, 'b', 2, 'c', 1, 'd', 2]

print(''.join(map(str, x)))
# A2B2C2D2a4b2c1d2
```

Answer (score 1):

`str(x)` gives the string representation of `x` - it doesn't iterate over the values in `x`. Try this:

```
print(''.join([str(a) for a in x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
print(''.join([str(k) for k in x]))
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
A2B2C2D2a4b2c1d2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['A', 2, 'B', 2, 'C', 2, 'D', 2, 'a', 4, 'b', 2, 'c', 1, 'd', 2]
```

**For understanding**:

```
s = ''                             # empty var
for elem in x:                     # for each elem in x
    s += str(elem)                 # concatenate it with prev s
print(s)                           # A2B2C2D2a4b2c1d2
```

**Which can be shorten to**:

```
print(''.join([str(elem) for elem in x]))  # A2B2C2D2a4b2c1d2
```

**Using reduce**:

```
print(reduce(lambda x,y:str(x)+str(y),x))   # A2B2C2D2a4b2c1d2
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by making a new list where all the elements from x have been converted to strings:

```
x = ['A', 2, 'B', 2, 'C', 2, 'D', 2, 'a', 4, 'b', 2, 'c', 1, 'd', 2]

strings = []

for e in x:
    strings.append(str(e))

print(''.join(strings))
```

The above answers are much cleaner though.