# String Compression using a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```
'''
Program to Compress a string using Dictonaries.

Input samle--> 'AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDaa'
output sample--> 'A4B4C4D4a2'

'''
# Function declaration
def string_compression(str):
    d = {}
    x = []

    # Generating Key-Value pair for entire string
    for i in str:
        if i not in d.keys():
            d[i] = 1
        else:
            d[i] = d[i] + 1

    # Copying Key Value Pairs in a list
    for key,value in d.items():
        x.append(key)
        x.append(value)

    # Printing a Cocktail list of Strings and Integers
    print(x)

    # Converting Integers in list x to Strings and Joining them
    for i in x[1::2]:
        x[i] = str(x[i])
    print(''.join(x))
    #print(''.join(map(str, x)))



y = 'AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDaa'
string_compression(y) # Function Call
```

Output:

```
['A', 4, 'B', 4, 'C', 4, 'D', 4, 'a', 2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "string_compression.py", line 36, in <module>
    string_compression(y) # Function Call
  File "string_compression.py", line 30, in string_compression
    x[i] = str(x[i])
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm able to print x as list,
But I'm unable to print the list in string format.

Also I tried all the possible combinations of solutions as per my previous post:
[Converting list of Integers and Strings to purely a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452661/converting-a-list-of-integers-and-strings-to-purely-a-string/55452843#55452843)

But The link's solutions are working only if I try to run the code in a new file taking only 2 lines of code as:

`x = ['A', 4, 'B', 4, 'C', 4, 'D', 4, 'a', 2]
print(''.join(map(str, x)))`

Why are any of the methods not working here in this above code? Any concept which I'm lagging?

Comment: You should not create a variable called `str`. You are hiding the built-in type `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the param from built-in keyword type `str` to something else, perhaps `s`, also switching to `map` in joining:

```
def string_compression(s):
    d = {}
    x = []

    # Generating Key-Value pair for entire string
    for i in s:
        if i not in d.keys():
            d[i] = 1
        else:
            d[i] = d[i] + 1

    # Copying Key Value Pairs in a list
    for key,value in d.items():
        x.append(key)
        x.append(value)

    # Printing a Cocktail list of Strings and Integers
    print(x)

    # Converting Integers in list x to Strings and Joining them
    for i in x[1::2]:
        x[i] = str(x[i])
    print(''.join(map(str, x)))



y = 'AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDaa'
string_compression(y) # Function Call
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['A', 4, 'B', 4, 'C', 4, 'D', 4, 'a', 2]
A4B4C4D4a2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your particular problem is you're using the name `str` for the argument of your function, which shadows the builtin `str()` function you're trying to call.

However, there are also some bugs in your algorithm – dictionaries aren't ordered (not before Python 3.6 anyway) so you aren't guaranteed that you get the same order of characters back. Also, if the input string is `aaaaabbbbbaaaaa`, you'll end up with something like `a10b5`, which isn't reversible to `aaaaaabbbbbaaaaa`. (I'm not going to go into how strings with numbers can't be "compressed" reversibly with this, but that's also an issue.)

I'd do something like this:

```py
def string_rle(s):
    parts = []
    for c in s:
        if not parts or c != parts[-1][0]:
            parts.append([c, 1])
        else:
            parts[-1][-1] += 1
    return ''.join('%s%d' % (part[0], part[1]) for part in parts)

print(string_rle('AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDaa'))
```

The idea is that `parts` holds an ordered list of pairs of a character and a count, and for each character in the original string, we see if the current pair (`parts[-1]`) has the same character; if it does, we increment the counter, otherwise, we generate a new pair.

Answer (score 0):

You have overritten the 'str' function in the function definition as a function argument:

```
def string_compression(str): # your argument overrides the 'str' function
```

so then when you are trying to call the 'str' function here:

```
x[i] = str(x[i])
```

you are actually calling the 'string_compression' argument, which is not callable.

Change the variable 'str' name to something else.

BTW, this for loop:

```
for i in x[1::2]:
    x[i] = str(x[i])
```

produces a list [C, a, C, C, C] which is not what you are looking for. You need to get the integers indexes not the integers itself.

```
for i in range(1,len(x),2):
    print str(x[i])
```